# Can I startup a http server that can be accessed only from the same process?

Tags: windows

I want to start a http server for a WebBrowser control in the same process, but I don't want other process to access, is there any way?

Comment: Why on earth would you need a webserver-webbrowser for inter-process communication?

Answer (score 1):

Opening a TCP/IP port (eg listening on a port) can be restricted to only the loop back interface (127.0.0.1) so only local processes can access it) but not the current process only. If you have no control over the web server implementation: you're doomed. If not: you could use  some information only known to your process and add a special header field which must be present for the web server to serve something. It's a kludge but it might work.